# Set the Visibility of Data Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

In my application I have 3 data grids in a single xaml file. Based on the User selection I want show one grid and hide other grids.

in my view model class I have Boolean property for each grid and based on the selection I am setting it to true or false.But all grids are visible .

```
    <DataGrid  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsGridVisible}" >
```

In my view model I am setting IsGridVisible value

```
public bool IsCapexGridVisible
    {
        get { return isCapexGridVisible; }
        set { isCapexGridVisible = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsCapexGridVisible"); }
    }
```

Please provide your ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility property on UIElement is not a boolean. It is an enum with three values:

**Collapsed**   Do not display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout.

**Hidden**  Do not display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout.

**Visible** Display the element.

So in order to set it properly from ViewModel you should:
- make your property type of Visibility (not best solution in the world)
- Use converter for the binding which will do the trick of translating boolean to visibility

```
  public class BooleanToCollapsedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(Visibility) && value is bool)
        {
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        throw new FormatException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: We can just set the visibility property in our view model class also like
private Visibility isPrGridVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;

Answer (score 10):

There is a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) available to you that converts `true` to `System.Windows.Visibility.Visible` and `false` to `System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed`.

So you can take help of this pre built converter and must add it to resources.

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
```

Create a property of type `bool` in your ViewModel

```
    bool _dgVisibility;
    public bool DataGridVisibility
    {
        get {  return _dgVisibility;  }
        set
        {
            _dgVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataGridVisibility");
        }
    }
```

and you can use it as below

```
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding Path=DataGridVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Comment: For other noobies like me, the resources section goes in your app.xaml file, not your View xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Additional converter variant with visibility customization

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;


[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(IValueConverter))]
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    [ConstructorArgument("TrueValue")]
    public Visibility TrueValue { get; set; }

    [ConstructorArgument("FalseValue")]
    public Visibility FalseValue { get; set; }

    [ConstructorArgument("NullValue")]
    public Visibility NullValue { get; set; }

    public BoolToVisibilityConverter()
    {
        TrueValue = Visibility.Visible;
        FalseValue = Visibility.Collapsed;
        NullValue = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return NullValue;

        if (value is not bool boolValue)
            return null;

        return boolValue ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Equals(value, TrueValue))
            return true;
        if (Equals(value, FalseValue))
            return false;
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<someControl ...
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ExampleNamespace.Converters;assembly=ExampleAssembly"
             ...
             >

...

Visibility="{Binding IsSearchInProgress, 
             Mode=OneWay, 
             Converter={converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"

Visibility="{Binding IsSearchInProgress, 
             Mode=OneWay, 
             Converter={converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter TrueValue=Collapsed, FalseValue=Visible}}"
```